# Spring Data how to reuse specifications in count query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data for my repositories and I want to be able to combine simple specifications to build complex queries. This is not a difficult task by using `Specifications` class and applying `and`, `or` helper methods and then calling `findAll` method of `JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>` class which accepts `Specification<T>`.

The main problem is where I want to reuse existing specifications and instead of directly getting the result list, apply a `count` aggregate function or a `groupBy` aggregate function to the specification and get the result of the aggregate function as a `Long` result or `List<Tuple>`.

To be more specific I put a simple example here:

```
public Specification<Person> getByNameSpec(String name) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        return builder.equal(root.get(Person_.firstName), name);
    };
}
```

In this example I have a method named `getByNameSpec` in my `PersonServiceImpl` class which is intended to be reused in multiple places. I want to use this specifications in three scenarios:

1. Count the number of people named "John"
2. Group people named "John" by another field like `job` and count of each group
3. Select only one or two fields of people named "John"

Note that I intend to use specifications heavily in this manner if these operations are possible. If this is not possible how should I create some basic criteria and reuse them all over my code?

Comment: One hint would be to read the implementation of SimpleJpaRepository and implement your own repository object inheriting the SimpleJpaRepository according to your need. At least goal #1 would be feasible.